# Using jquery $(this) in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Quick Description:**
I'm aware that using $(this) in a function won't work because it's not within the right scope. I've also seen other similar questions. I just still can't figure out how to fix my scenerio.

**Goal:** I'm trying to build a panoramic photo viewer with jQuery. I have it working, but I need multiple instances. So I need to target only the one I'm hovering on.

**Code:**

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/5J3rh/

Simplified Code:

```
var hoverInterval;

function doStuff() {

/* The next line is the one in question */

    $(this).animate({
      /* stuff happening */
    });
}

$(function() {
    $('.pan-wrap').hover(
        function() {
            /* stuff happening */
            hoverInterval = setInterval(doStuff, 250);
        },
        function() {
            clearInterval(hoverInterval);
   });
});
```

Comment: *I'm aware that using $(this) in a function won't work because it's not within the right scope.* — Scope doesn't matter. It is context that matters.

Comment: use the $.proxy() function to set the context of this.

Comment: Look on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5J3rh/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have scope issues, this in the doStuff is window context.

Use [proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
hoverInterval = setInterval($.proxy(doStuff,this), 250);
```

Comment: Oh neat! I didn't know about `proxy()`. +1

Comment: Thank you, this is the missing piece I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly pass `this` into `doStuff`:

```
setInterval(function() {
    doStuff(this);
}, 250);
```

And in `doStuff` you can do:

```
function doStuff(element) {
    ...
}
```

Or you can explicitly set the value of `this` for `doStuff` like so:

```
setInterval(function() {
    doStuff.call(this);
}, 250);
```

Then you can still use `$(this)` inside `doStuff` without changing any of its arguments. For more information on `call`, see [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and its friend [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).